# Render Controller in Symfony doesn't work

Tags: symfony-3.1

I use Symfony 3.1.2 and try to implement a simple navigation template (twig) inside base.html.twig.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
    {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Navigation:topNavigation')) }}
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

The navigation.html.twig template in the default directory looks like this

```
    <div id="navigation-wrapper">
        <ul id="navigation">
        {% for item in navigation %}
            <li><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.label }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The NavigationController in AppBundle/Controller looks like this

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class NavigationController extends Controller
    {
        public function topNavigation()
        {
            $navigation = array(
                array("url"=>"/login", "label"=>"Login"),
                array("url"=>"/register", "label"=>"Registrieren")
             );

            return $this->render('default/navigation.html.twig', array(
                'navigation' => $navigation,));
        }
}
```

There is no error, NavigationController->topNavigation didn't run, nothing is rendering and i don't know what to do. Has anyone a idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine. You must have suffix `Action` to every controller method. Your method in `NavigationController` should be like :

```
public function topNavigationAction() {
    $navigation = array(
        array("url" => "/login", "label" => "Login"),
        array("url" => "/register", "label" => "Registrieren")
    );

    return $this->render('default/navigation.html.twig', array(
            'navigation' => $navigation,
    ));
}
```

It will work for sure.

Comment: Thanks, that works, it was a typical beginner Error to forget the Action-Suffix. Thanks for fast response!